# No clipboard support with X11forwarding?

Tags: ubuntu, x11, macintosh

I've successfully setup X11forwarding from Linux to Mac. Now I'm able to run Thunar and get a window locally.

But the clipboard is not shared between the Thunar window and Mac computer.

Any ideas?

Comment: Taking “thunar” out of the picture for a moment, what do you get with ``xclip -in <<<whatever`` on one end and ``xclip -o`` on the other?

Comment: @phg Weird, there's no xclip on Xquartz, but I just found out there's a preference dialog. I just need to check `Enable syncing` in Pasteboard tab. Now it works ....

Answer (score 2):

As phg pointed out, it wasn't a SSH issue ... I just need to enable pasteboard syncing locally, e.g

[image]